# cannot find symbol method append (String)

Tags: java, netbeans

I don't get it why it says it cannot find symbol append.
do i need to use Stringbuffer? i got this code on a tutorial for receipts from youtube, and the uploader disabled comments so I can't ask him directly. please help me. Im still an amateur at java.
Tell me if I need to post my whole code or what code would you want to see to see errors. thanks in adv.

```
   Calendar timer = Calendar.getInstance();
   timer.getTime();
   SimpleDateFormat tTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
   tTime.format(timer.getTime());
   SimpleDateFormat Tdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
   Tdate.format(timer.getTime());

         jtxtReceipt.append("\ Water Station Receipt:\n" +
           "Reference:\t\t\t" + refs +

           "\n=========================================\n" +
           "Mineral:\t\t\t" + jtxtMineral.getText() + "\n\n" +
           "Purified:\t\t\t" + jtxtPurified.getText() + "\n\n" +
           "Travel:\t\t\t" + jtxtTravel.getText() + "\n\n" +    
           "VAT:\t\t\t" + jtxtVat.getText() + "\n"+
            "\n========================================\n" + "\n"  +
           "Tax:\t\t\t" + jtxtTax2.getText() + "\n" +
           "Subtotal:\t\t\t" + jtxtSubTotal.getText() + "\n" +
           "Total:\t\t\t" + jtxtTotal.getText() + "\n" + 

           "===========================================" +
           "\nDate:" + Tdate.format(timer.getTime()) +
           "\ntTime:" + tTime.format(timer.getTime()) +
           "\n\t\tThank you ");
```

Comment: It seems that you have declared jtxtReceipt as String and that class got no append method.

Comment: do i have to declare append as String and not jtxtReceipt?

Comment: and where can i put append method? i tried reviewing the tutorial but I can't see what I've done wrong. I only followed what the tutorial says

Comment: provide jtxtReceipt declaration. is it String or any other?

Comment: append is a method, jtxtReceipt is an object. Are you sure that you have followed the tutorial correctly? It seems that jtxtReceipt is not ment to be a String.

Comment: I already checked and review it again to see how he declared append but I can't find it. I'll review it again

Comment: append method does not need to be declared, the problem is in jtxtReceipt. Could you share its declaration in your code?

Comment: where you have declared jtxtReceipt

Comment: I honestly can't find it. that's my only error how could i miss that on that tutorial

Comment: can I paste the link of the tutorial? He did it on the last part, so you can see. He only fast forward it, and previewed the code he wrote

Comment: that's why i dont know where he declared the jtxtReceipt

Comment: Paste the link but maybe you should choose another non-video tutorial that explains code better.

Answer (score 1):

The `append` method doesn't exist in the `String` class. You can either user a `StringBuilder` to do the job, or if it's a light concatenation, just use the `+` operator

Answer (score 0):

The **append** method doesn't work on **TextField** Palette. So, if You're on **TextField Palette**, replacing that with **TextArea Palette** should solve the problem.